# Draw an Organization chart from xml data with wpf

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I need to figure out a solution to draw Data From an XML file into an organization chart programmatically with a wpf application.

I could not find any free library for this purpose, and  I am trying effortlessly to code it by myself.

[The out put must be somthing like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccy1e.gif)

Comment: You have to read up on how to draw shapes on a [`Canvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netframework-4.8): [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview).  
If you know this, you can draw the chart. An organizational chart is a tree structure (or graph). You have to know [how to traverse a tree](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/tree_traversal.htm). Then for each node you create `Shape` (node).

Comment: You can use the [`XmlDocument Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8) or [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) to walk through the XML. This way you can avoid the need to know anything about tree graphs. Once you know how to draw and how to walk through the hierarchy of a XML, the task is quite simple.

Comment: [LINQ To XML Tutorials with Examples](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples)

Comment: I think I can do that, but the major difficulty here is how to link the nodes with lines to make it look like an organization chart

Comment: A `Line` uses two coordinates to describe the position, length and orientation: a start point and an end point. When you store the current position of each `Shape` in a dedicated property, you can bind the line's start point to one `Shape` and the end point to the other. If you don't want to create your own shape (e.g. derive from `Rectangle`) you can use attached property. An attached property might be the preferred solution to store the position of each `Shape`.

Comment: The lines in your example diagram are orthogonal. This means you have to compose a line of several lines. Orthogonal means each line must have either the same _x_ coordinate (horizontal) OR the same _y_ coordinate (vertical). Now draw the appropriate number of lines until you reach from `Shape` A's position to `Shape`B's position. In case of orthogonal connections you can't use a binding. You might compose the whole graph in code-behind.

Comment: Arrange the nodes by calculating the center point and then try to align them vertically (try stacking by center point first) and horizontally (with equally distributed space between them).